# Program error that measures the parameters of matrix multiplication

Tags: c, performance, cpu, clock, rdtsc

I'm writing a program that measures the performance of matrix multiplication with `rdtsc()`, Read Time Stamp Counter.

However, when I combined the matrix multiplication program and performance measurement program, errors appeared.

I would appreciate if you could let know me how to change my current code for debugging.

Environment: macOS Mojave version 10.14.5, terminal 2.9.5

When I execute the program for matrix multiplication itself, `matrixmul.c`, the compilation succeeds and the output is correct. However, if I add the performance measurement it fails to compile.

Here's `matrixmul.c`:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 3
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double A[N][N] = {
        {1.0, 3.0, 1.0},
        {3.0, 1.0, 3.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double B[N][N] = {
        {6.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 6.0},
        {6.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double C[N][N] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    };
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            printf("C[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j, C[i][j]);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./matrixmul
C[0][0] = 6.000000
C[0][1] = 5.000000
C[0][2] = 19.000000
C[1][0] = 18.000000
C[1][1] = 7.000000
C[1][2] = 9.000000
C[2][0] = 6.000000
C[2][1] = 3.000000
C[2][2] = 7.000000
```

Here's `measurement.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rdtsc.h"

#define N 3
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long start = rdtsc();

    double A[N][N] = {
        {1.0, 3.0, 1.0},
        {3.0, 1.0, 3.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double B[N][N] = {
        {6.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 6.0},
        {6.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double C[N][N] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    };
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            printf("C[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j, C[i][j]);
        
    unsigned long long stop = rdtsc();
    printf("measured time : %I64d [clock]\n", stop - start);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's `rdtsc.h` (this program is located in the same folder of `measurement.c`):

```c
#ifndef RDTSC_H_
#define RDTSC_H_

inline unsigned long long rdtsc() {
    unsigned long long ret;
    __asm__ volatile ("rdtsc" : "=A" (ret));
    return ret;
}

#endif /* RDTSC_H_ */
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -o measurement measurement.c
measurement.c:38:30: warning: length modifier 'I64' results in undefined
      behavior or no effect with 'd' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
    printf("measured time : %I64d [clock]\n", stop - start);
                            ~^~~~
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rdtsc", referenced from:
      _main in measurement-510357.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## trial following the answer

I have fixed my code and executed it again, but still I had one error.
error message

```
$ gcc -o measurement measurement.c
measurement.c:38:53: error: use of undeclared identifier 'start'
    printf("measured time : %lld [clock]\n", stop - start);
                                                    ^
1 error generated.
```

measurement.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rdtsc.h"

#define N 3
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //unsigned long long start = rdtsc();

    double A[N][N] = {
        {1.0, 3.0, 1.0},
        {3.0, 1.0, 3.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double B[N][N] = {
        {6.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 6.0},
        {6.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

    double C[N][N] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    };
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            printf("C[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j, C[i][j]);
        
    unsigned long long stop = rdtsc();
    printf("measured time : %lld [clock]\n", stop - start);

    return 0;
}
```

rdtsc.h

```
#ifndef RDTSC_H_
#define RDTSC_H_

unsigned long long rdtsc() {
    unsigned long long ret;
    __asm__ volatile ("rdtsc" : "=A" (ret));
    return ret;
}

#endif /* RDTSC_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to make the `rdtsc` function `inline`, it only confuses the compiler about whether or not to export the function. Just remove it or add `extern` before it to explicitly tell the compiler to export the function. This will work:

```
#ifndef RDTSC_H_
#define RDTSC_H_

unsigned long long rdtsc() {
    unsigned long long ret;
    __asm__ volatile ("rdtsc" : "=A" (ret));
    return ret;
}

#endif /* RDTSC_H_ */
```

Also, as `clang` says, `%I64d` is an invalid format modifier. Use `%lld` instead for `long long int`.

Comment: The `%I64d` notation is used on Windows; it is not portable to any other platform.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thank you for your answer. I have added the trial following your answer on my question post and appreciate if you could give me extra advice to fix it.